println AndroidStudio Unicode UTF-8 characters incorrect?
println AndroidStudio Unicode UTF-8 Incorrect character display
Kotlin class:
class StudentModel{
}
fun main(){
    println("This is a language Vietnamese: Tiếng Việt")
}

Output: This is a language Vietnamese: Ti?ng Vi?t
EX image:
ImageBB UTF-8 Code Running
I'm having a problem with the println command. It's not displaying Unicode UTF-8 characters correctly
I've done a lot of research, and set everything related to UTF-8 encoding that I can do.
Everything I've tried:

File - Setting - File Encoding (Everything set to UTF-8)
VMOptions add the code: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
In ProjectFolder (I edited build.gradle.kts to compileOptions and passed the encode = "UTF-8" parameter)
And many other ways that I found on StackOverFlow but also failed.

And of course all failed.
Have you ever gotten the println command to work with UTF-8 please show me and everyone?
I'm currently using the version: Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1, Build #AI-242.23339.11.2421.12483815, built on October 11, 2024, Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Please [edit] and provide a [mre] and explain how you start it so we can test ourselves and add a screenshot of that example so we can see where exactly the issue arises.

Thank you very much, I have tried to edit the article as short as possible, hope everyone can take some time to consider the problem.
